# How do I remove a word that contains a dash from a text?

Tags: java, string, replaceall

so I want to remove a word that contains a dash between them like **off-campus** alongside other things that I want to remove. here is my code so far.

```
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

String text;
//text: CS 204 is a wonderful class. So WONDERFUL ! amazing class. cleaver class. must-remove
System.out.print("Please Enter Text: ");
text = read.nextLine();
System.out.println(text);
String n = text.replaceAll("[\\.\\!\\d]", "");
System.out.println(n);
```

so far it prints

> CS  is a wonderful class So WONDERFUL  amazing class cleaver class must-remove

Comment: Please give the actual output and the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regex `\w+-\w+`, which means 2 words `\w+`, separated by a dash, and you use

```
"CS 204 is a wonderful class. So WONDERFUL ! must-remove".replaceAll("\\w+-\\w+", "") 
// CS 204 is a wonderful class. So WONDERFUL !
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted now I just have to figure out how to combine it with the rest of the regexs

Comment: @GTurkistane you're not mandatory to combine the regex, you can chain the calls of repalceAll ;)